# Translate Animation coordinates issues multiple devices

Tags: android, animation

I want to translate an object from the center of my screen to the top left corner of my screen.

I want the translate anim to be same on all devices 
currently the translate values i give are different on different devices[after animation position of object is different].

Is there a way to translate and pass values which will result the animation to be same across devices?

[image]

My Code

```
ObjectAnimator scaleDownX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(progressWidget, "scaleX", 0.355f);
        ObjectAnimator scaleDownY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(progressWidget, "scaleY", 0.355f);
        scaleDownX.setDuration(3000);
        scaleDownY.setDuration(3000);

        ObjectAnimator translateX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(progressWidget, "translationX", -435f);
        translateX.setRepeatCount(0);
        translateX.setDuration(3000);

        ObjectAnimator translateY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(progressWidget, "translationY", -295f);
        translateY.setRepeatCount(0);
        translateY.setDuration(3000);


        //sequential animation
        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.play(scaleDownX).with(scaleDownY).with(translateX).with(translateY);
        //set.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

[image]

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state_list_drawable"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle state) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, state);
    final View content = getView();
content.findViewById(R.id.fragment_imageView).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            translateWithScale(v);
        }
    });
}

private final void translateWithScale(View target) {
    if (target == null) {
        return;
    }
    // cancel animator
    if (target.getTag() instanceof Animator) {
        ((Animator) target.getTag()).cancel();
    }

    // params
    final int duration = 300;
    final float scale = 0.355f;

    // scale
    ObjectAnimator scaleDownX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "scaleX", scale).setDuration(duration);
    ObjectAnimator scaleDownY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "scaleY", scale).setDuration(duration);

    //
    final float transY = target.getTop() + target.getHeight() / 2 - scale * target.getHeight() / 2;
    final float transX = target.getLeft() + target.getWidth() / 2 - scale * target.getWidth() / 2;
    ObjectAnimator translateX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "translationX", -transX).setDuration(duration);
    ObjectAnimator translateY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "translationY", -transY).setDuration(duration);

    // sequential animator
    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    set.playTogether(scaleDownX, scaleDownY, translateX, translateY);
    set.start();

    // set the AnimatorSet as a tag, to cancel for animate next time.
    target.setTag(set);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    View progressWidget=null;

    progressWidget.setPivotX(0);
    progressWidget.setPivotY(0);

    ObjectAnimator scaleDownX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(progressWidget, "scaleX", 0.355f);
    ObjectAnimator scaleDownY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(progressWidget, "scaleY", 0.355f);
    scaleDownX.setDuration(3000);
    scaleDownY.setDuration(3000);


    //the top left corner of screen location is [0,0], get ProgressBar left top location in screen use getLocationInWindow
    int[] location = new int[2];
    progressWidget.getLocationInWindow(location);

    ObjectAnimator translateX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(progressWidget, "translationX", -location[0]);//location[0] is x location, so move -location[0]
    translateX.setRepeatCount(0);
    translateX.setDuration(3000);

    ObjectAnimator translateY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(progressWidget, "translationY", -location[1]);//location[1] is y location, so move -location[1]
    translateY.setRepeatCount(0);
    translateY.setDuration(3000);
```

Comment: hey thanks,if its not too much of a bother can you explain what your snippet is doing?

Comment: add some explanation

Comment: not working,doesnt go to top edge (0,0) , why -location[0]?

Comment: it translates only halfway ,not all the way to top edge

Comment: see updated answer. default, View scale X and Y, the pivot is View's center. so the pivot must reset to View left top corner.

Comment: is this issue because im using scale animation with translation?

Answer (score 1):

First: You must create xml have two control

Control 1 have name ***mControlStart*** have location at ***centre layout***

Control 2 have name ***mControlFinish*** have location at ***top left*** and have properties

```
  android:visibility="invisible"
```

Then in OnClick

```
private void setUpAnimation() {
    int[] startPosition = new int[2];
    int[] endPosition = new int[2];
    mControlStart.getLocationInWindow(startPosition);
    mControlFinish.getLocationInWindow(endPosition);
    int offset = endPosition[1] - startPosition[1];
    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, offset, 0, 0);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    mControlStart.startAnimation(animation);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            mControlStart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mControlFinish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
}
```